# Angular/CSS: grid of dynamically resizable objects

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

I have an API fetching json data that I'm representing as small colored blocks.
Right now I have a fixed height and width for these blocks.
My question is how can I modify the size of these blocks so that when the count of objects keep increasing, the size of these blocks keep decreasing, ensuring that the size of the parent container fits within the page. I also want the option of being able to display only say, 200 blocks at a time

HTML

```
<div class="ui-array-resources">
    <div  *ngFor="let resource of filteredResources;" class="ui-array-resource" (click)="resourceDidClick(resource)"    
                    [ngClass]="{'ui-status-not-connected': resource.primary_status==='NC',
                    'ui-status-sleeping': resource.primary_status==='SLP',
                    'ui-status-inactive': resource.primary_status==='IA',
                    'ui-status-available': resource.primary_status==='GI',
                    'selected-resource': resource === selectedResource}">
      </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.ui-array-resources {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px dashed lightgray;
    padding: 30px;
    margin:50px;
    position: relative;

    .ui-array-resource {
        width:30px;
        height: 30px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        margin: 1px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        &.selected-resource {box-shadow: inset 1px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
        &:hover {
            transform: scale(1.5);
            border: 1px solid white;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            box-shadow: none;
                }
        &.ui-status-not-connected {background-color: #EF5350;}
        &.ui-status-available {background-color: #66BB6A;}
        &.ui-status-sleeping {background-color: #FFCA28;}
        &.ui-status-inactive {background-color: #D3D3D3;}  
}
}
```

[image: mock up of current display]

I went through several articles and solutions but nothing seems to work for an undefined large number of such embeddedd objects.

Comment: Well, in order to modify the size of all those squares, I would apply them a [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to the CSS properties `width` and `height` of each of them, linked to an Angular property aware of the number of blocks you have. The rest is mathematics. Sorry, I can't write a complete answer based on the code you posted, but I gave you an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot @amedina that was exactly what I was looking for!
This is what I did-
I added an ngStyle property for the width and height property.

HTML

```
 <div class="ui-array-resources">
                        <div  *ngFor="let resource of filteredResources;" class="ui-array-resource" (click)="resourceDidClick(resource)"    
                        [ngStyle]="{'width':width + 'px', 'height':height + 'px'}"
                        [ngClass]="{'ui-status-not-connected': resource.primary_status==='NC',
                        'ui-status-sleeping': resource.primary_status==='SLP',
                        'ui-status-inactive': resource.primary_status==='IA',
                        'ui-status-available': resource.primary_status==='GI',
                        'selected-resource': resource === selectedResource}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I later checked the count of the objects to modify those properties in the ngDoCheck lifecycle method.

TS

```
width=10;
height=10;

 ngDoCheck(){

    if(this.filteredResources){
      if(this.filteredResources.length<20){
      this.width=30;
      this.height=30;
      }
}
}
```